# Avoid scrolling the page with touch while navbar is open

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In mobile Chrome when I touch-scroll over the open `navbar`, the page scrolls behind it, which is very annoying. Furthermore, when my `navbar` has many items, and it scrolls as well, then when reaching the top or bottom, the scroll will continue on the page, which is even more annoying and and a quite bad user experience overall.

Is there any way to trap touch-scroll events in the `.navbar-collapse` container, so that they won't affect anything out of that?

What I've tried so far is something like this

```
$(".navbar-collapse").on("touchmove", function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

but it seems to be ineffective, I guess this behavior is much deeper in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

just try to add this in your custom css

```
@media(max-width:780px)
{
.navbar
 {
       position: absolute;
width: 100%;
max-height: 500px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
 }
}
```